# how to set the box model size to the size of its content in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new in HTML/CSS. I'm trying to build a navigation of a site. I am using unordered list. width of the box model of list items and ul itself is full line. If i set display to inline the options will be lined in one line (which I don't want). If I use blocked display box models take entire line again. Only option I can think of is to set the width by hand, and I am looking for a way to set width and height of a box model according to its content. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. First suggestion is you read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you tell me what my mistake is ?

Comment: What I could understand is you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/douzap03/ ? ----- Without the code you have, I can't help you any further. Please add your CSS/HTML, and include image to showcase what you expect the output to be. Use the snippets or jsfiddle.